# Save PDF in 1.3 version

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp with my project to generate PDF. Everything works fine. However the generated PDF version is 1.4. And I need the PDF Version 1.3. I'm using latest version of iTextSharp. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon, Well that didn't worked for me, I m posting working now

Comment: What do you need: A PDF containing a 1.3 as version in the header or a PDF only using PDF features from 1.3?

Comment: @mkl, i want the generated pdf to be compatible with Acrobat 4.x version.  Actually the final PDF is sent to media for print and media rejected pdf version 1.4

Comment: Can I assume from your answer that you found a way?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work as suggested in other solutions

```
_PdfWriter.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_3)
```

This did work

```
 _PdfWriter.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_3;
```